# Do I need to check out and check in my baggage again in transit airport?

Tags: usa, transit, qatar-airways, us-airways, philadelphia

I am flying from Doha to Philadelphia by Qatar Airway. While in Philadelphia, I need to change flight to US Airway. But I only have 1 hour and a half before my next flight to Birmingham. Do I have enough time to check out and check in my baggage?

1.Kuala Lumpur (KUL) 
Tue, 21 Jul 2015 20:50

2.Doha (DOH) 
Tue, 21 Jul 2015 23:20

3.Doha (DOH) 
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 01:10

4. Philadelphia (PHL) 
   Wed, 22 Jul 2015 07:45

5.Philadelphia (PHL) 
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 09:40
Terminal F

6.Birmingham (BHM) 
Wed, 22 Jul 2015 11:00

Comment: You can find historical wait times for US passport control at http://awt.cbp.gov/

Comment: did you book these as flights on separate bookings? or did you go through a travel agency or online website? An agency should be able to tell you and move these if they think you won't be able to make your next flight.

Answer (score 4):

Your title and your question don't match.  So I'm not sure what you're asking, but I'll answer both questions.

1. Do I need to check out and check in my baggage again in transit airport?

   **Yes.** You must gather your checked bag and pass through US customs at the airport where you enter the country.  Then you must re-check your bag (even if on the same airline), and pass through TSA security before boarding your onward flight.
2. Do I have enough time to check out and check in my baggage?

   **Maybe.** 1.5 hours might be plenty of time, if you can get through US immigration and customs and TSA security quickly.  If there are no lines, you could be through all of that in 10 minutes.  On the other hand, if it's a busy time of day, it could take 2 hours just to do that.  It's really hard to predict sometimes.  If you can tell us what time your flight arrives, someone familiar with the Philadelphia airport may be able to provide additional insight as to the expected delay at that time.

Comment: regarding baggage; [U.S. Customs and Border Protection Q&A](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/992/~/checking-baggage-through-to-your-connecting-flight-via-airlines)

Comment: and quite a detailed forum post on flyertalk http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/us-airways-dividend-miles-pre-consolidation/958317-us-guide-phl-philadelphia-airport.html

Comment: "Then you must re-check your bag (even if on the same airline), and pass through TSA security before boarding your onward flight." Often times, for people with connecting flights, there is a place after customs that collects your baggage, and you do not have to exit security.

Comment: @user102008: I don't believe this is true.  They often let you re-check your baggage immediately after customs, but then you still have to re-clear security. The only benefit is that you don't have to go back through the "main" security checkpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Flimzys answer: In normal conditions you should have enough time to make the connection in PHL but you come in at a time where a lot of the European flights get in as well, so it will be busy and there is a non-zero chance that you'll miss it.

If it's all booked on the same ticket, the airline is responsible of getting you to BMH. If this will require to stay the night, they will have to put you up in a hotel and give you some food vouchers are well.

If it's not booked on the same ticket, you carry all the risk and have to negotiate with the second carrier how to get to BMH. This will include almost certainly a hefty change fee. Consider a travel insurance that covers this type of thing.